# Multi-Level Bullets Implementation

Tags: php, list, organization

What is the best way of implementing multi-level lists/bullets in php?

What I'm trying to implement is a system to take in short phrases, and categorize them within sections. However, at the same time, I would like to have each section to be collapsible and capable of having sub-sections within them.

For Example:
Section 10
Section 10.X
Section 10.X.X

I was thinking of having each sub-layer as an array, but I realize that I've seen the same type of collapsibility in many places, and they all seem to be similar. Maybe there already is a package or library that does this? And if there is, how should my data-structure for keeping each entry be structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bullets are being done in HTML, as PHP merely generates HTML code. Consider using nested <ul> tags.

The collapsing is most probably going to be javasscript. (Although I wonder if the CSS *:active* psuedoclass would work in supportive browsers...)

Regarding the package, I'm not sure. You essentially need a recursive list generating function.

Comment: What would be the best way of storing this on the server-side? Nested Arrays?

Comment: That might work. Nested Arrays are called "Multi-dimensional" arrays. I'm no expert. Just pointing out that you're not just focusing on PHP here... Also, Sarfraz has a point with Tree View, although I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

For the kind of structure you mentioned, i think you need what is know as **[Tree View](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/package/5602.html)**. Check it out on how to implement that.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Anything to do with toggling, display lists, indenting etc should be achieved relatively easily with HTML/CSS/Javascript.

Inside your category table, you could create a parent_id field which matches to your primary ID. Then run  loops to display your TLD as well as another loop to display the categories within the parent.